# Django two for Compare Values list update?

Tags: django

I would like to compare the values in the two statements and update them if there are any other values.

update records of database by the posted data

models.py

```
    class RecommendLaywer(models.Model):
        category_idx = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        lawyer_idx = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        register_date = models.DateTimeField()
        update_date = models.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'recommend_laywer'
            verbose_name_plural = "recommend laywer"
```

models.py

````
    ```
        if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
            print(request.POST)

            category_list = request.POST.getlist('arr_category[]')
            lawyer_list = request.POST.getlist('arr_lawyer[]')
            print("category_list1=====", category_list)
            print("lawyer_list2=====", lawyer_list)

            for lawyer in lawyer_list:
                for lawyer in lawyer_list:
                    ??????????????????????????

        code = 0
        msg = "TEST."

        data = json.dumps({
            'code': code,
            'msg': msg,
            #'retURL': retURL

        })
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```
````

console print.....

```
category_list1===== ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
lawyer_list2===== ['65', '37', '57', '58', '130', '62', '38', '51', '110']
```

The value of category_list1 is fixed.

```
1=65
2=37
3=57
4=58
..........
```

When the value of lawyer_list2 is changed,
I want to update.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? like How it should be compared and what need to be updated?

Comment: The value of category_list1 is the value of category_idx in the recommendLaywer model, and the value of lawyer_list2 is the value of lawyer_idx. If the value of lawyer_idx is changed, Attempt to change lawyer_idx based on category_idx I want to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to update records of database by the posted data, try this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import RecommendLawyer


@csrf_exempt
def recommend_add(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)    
        category_list = request.POST.getlist("arr_category[]")
        lawyer_list = request.POST.getlist("arr_lawyer[]")
        print("category_list1=====", category_list)
        print("lawyer_list2=====", lawyer_list)
        for category_id, lawyer_id in zip(category_list, lawyer_list):
            RecommendLawyer.objects.filter(category_idx=category_id).update(
                lawyer_idx=lawyer_id
            )

    code = 0
    msg = "TEST."

    data = {
        "code": code,
        "msg": msg,
        # 'retURL': retURL
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```